# multithread initialization synchronisation

Tags: java, multithreading

Might I ask here for a piece of advice.

I am creating several threads in the constructor of my class as I had a performance issue as I would like to add on more of series and flows. However those threads takes random time to initialize which means the code still execute and putting aside the order of my array list is now messed up, it is not fully loaded when the code keeps executing.

Series is a wrapper which add listeners and to simplify output a series of ArrayList that my frame needs to instantiate a chart in a panel.

what is the correct way to proceed here. I feel I do it all wrong.

```
    new Thread(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            Flow flow = new Flow(idThread, 1);
            flows.add(flow);
            series.add(new Series(3000, ProcessingType.NONE, flow, controller));
            series.add(new Series(5000, ProcessingType.FILTER, flow, controller));
        }
    }).start();

    new Thread(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            Flow flow = new Flow(idThread, 2);
            flows.add(flow);
            series.add(new Series(4000, ProcessingType.NONE, flow, controller));
            series.add(new Series(5000, ProcessingType.FILTER, flow, controller));
        }
    }).start();

    Global.getInstance().mySeries(idThread, series);
    trading = new Trading(idThread);
```

I try naively a

```
while (series.size()<10){
        try {
            Thread.sleep(10);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

However "logically" the main thread should sleep and allow time for the other ones to initialize?

Thanks

Comment: Why don't you just not start the threads until you are ready?

Comment: More specifically, instead of instantiating `Thread` directly, extend it, allow the thread objects to do some stuff in the constructor, then start them when you are ready.

Comment: Also, it is very unclear what the different objects you are referring to do and are. Please explain what `series`, `flow`, etc. are.

Comment: I see, I think it is what I was missing here. Thanks, let me check

Comment: There's no apparent need to extend `Thread`, but certainly you can construct all the `Thread` objects you want, and then start them all after the last has been initialized.

Comment: Alternatively, you can use a `Lock`, a `Barrier`, or good old low-level `wait()` / `notifyAll()` in the implementation of your parallel tasks to ensure that none of the threads proceeds until you are ready.

Comment: my issue is that I need those threads (thus series and flows) so if the arraylist series is not loaded it is causing me problems. I cannot start those threads when I am ready as I am in the opposite way. I need those threads to be ready. I have updated my question with your comments.

Answer (score 1):

Don't extend `Thread`, implement `Runnable`. Don't start new threads from within a constructor unless you really like weird bugs. You can use various synchronization idioms such as https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CountDownLatch.html to "line the horses up at the gate before the race".

Answer (score 0):

You can use a `CyclicBarrier`, where you can call `await()` method in main, until all you thread have reached this barrier your main thread will wait.

http://tutorials.jenkov.com/java-util-concurrent/cyclicbarrier.html

Comment: @matel you can call wait() on arraylist series in main when it is not loaded, and any thread adds to series  will call notify() or notifyAll(), to start processing.